# rpy2 problems with no error

Tags: python, rpy2

Hi~~ I wanna use rpy2 in my python.

I use anaconda and pycharm.

I install rpy2 in anaconda using conda install rpy2.

and now I wanna use rpy2 in pycharm.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2' # r 환경변수 입력 안하면 안됨

import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as r
import pandas.rpy.common as com

trainFile = r'D:\raw data\서울시 공공데이터\3.초기-16년5월분1\17.상권-추정매출\tbsm_trdar_selng.txt\tbsm_trdar_selng_utf8.txt'

pwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(trainFile))
trainData = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(trainFile),sep='|',
                header=None ,
                usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,11],
                names=['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CD_NM', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD','SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM','THSMON_SELNG_AMT'],
                dtype = { '0' : int},
                encoding='utf-8' )
os.chdir(pwd)

trainData = trainData.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD' ]).sum().reset_index() #합치기

trainData = trainData.pivot_table(index='STDR_YM_CD', values='THSMON_SELNG_AMT' , columns='TRDAR_CD', aggfunc=np.mean)
print(trainData.head())
```

after running this command, I didn't get any error message.
But interesting situation happened up.
Below is my result.

```
"C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\python.exe" "D:/python code/sales analysis/test.py"
Process finished with exit code 10
```

Pycharm finished their code at line 10.
They just import package and stop.
I don't know why. plz help me.

EDIT
When I use this code debug mode, I got it

```
"C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52786 --file "D:/python code/sales analysis/test.py"
pydev debugger: process 7608 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

Process finished with exit code 10
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 ? If not, give it a try. If still not working, the recommendation would be to try with linux or OS X.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6. I use window 10. And I don't ever use linux.
Is it difficult??